# Missing mounting brackets for DVD drive

Tags: dvd, case

Anyone here ever buy a PC case that did not come with mounting brackets for the DVD drive?  I bought a barebones DVD drive (Lite-On) and a case (Antec Sonata III 500).   The case came with nice mounting brackets for the hard drives, but none apparently for the optical drive bays.   Has anyone else experienced this?   Would it be possible to purchase these anywhere if this is common?  I tried some mounting brackets from another Antec case I own and they don't appear to fit.

Comment: http://www.antec.com/pdf/manuals/SonataIII_manual_EN.pdf The manual for the case i think, if anyone needs a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A case I bought a while back had the mounting brackets inside the removable bay covers. Not sure how common that practice is, but I'd take a close look at your case before assuming they're missing. Otherwise, I'd be surprised if you could get them from anyone except the manufacturer. There should be an 800 number or web address in your documentation somewhere that you can call or visit for support; that would be where I'd start.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  No idea how I missed that.

Comment: Glad you found them! :)

Comment: I wonder if those are the *HDD screws (grommets already inserted in drive trays) … Clear silicone grommets (already installed in drive trays)* mentioned in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](http://www.antec.com/pdf/manuals/SonataIII_manual_EN.pdf) seems to indicate that you don’t actually screw in 5¼" devices, but rather *snap* them in place. Compare the installation instructions (p 10) for 5¼" drives to 3½" drives:

> Place your 3.5”device in the tray. Using the screws provided with the drive tray, securely fasten your 3.5” device to the tray.

> Slide your 5.25” device into the drive bay, making sure to engage the 5.25” drive tray rails on either side of the bay.

Also, the parts list on page five specifically has no mention of 5¼" brackets.

Finally, notice from the images of the case that are no screw-holes or bracket slots in the 5¼" cage:
[image]

Comment: The mounting brackets were behind (and attached to) the 5.25" drive bay covers.  I had to screw the DVD drive to the brackets and then it slid and locked into place.

Comment: @KyleB., yes, that's [what I assumed](http://superuser.com/questions/438090/missing-mounting-brackets-for-dvd-drive/438098#comment505974_438091).